# Is it better to avoid inlnine SQL with dapper?

Tags: dapper

I have considered using `dapper`, but I still don't like the idea of using inline SQL.  Are there any thoughts on just have `stored procedures` so in the event that there is a problem with the query, it would not need a `recompilation`, but just a change to a `stored procedure` in a database.  Are there any alternatives such as keeping all `SQL queries` in it's own class library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper supports both options, and has no opinion on the topic.

Your question suggests that deployment of your codebase is tricky. If this is client-side code, that might make sense. For server-side code, it is usually easier to re-deploy the app than it is to change a stored procedure - ideally 1 click via something like TeamCity. Of course, your stored procedures should *also* have process / deployment control.

Having the SQL in a class library won't buy you much: you still need to re-deploy to get the changes. Of course, it may make sense to have your data-oriented code in separate assemblies to the UI (etc) code, but that is a local architecture decision.